# How to update cache for a Sitecore Web Api output upon the index update

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc

I am implementing Sitecore 8 Web Api. To be exact, i am using ServiceApiController in Sitecore Services Infrastructre. I wonder how can I cache the JSON output from this controller in such a way that it gets updated only if the lucene index which I am fetching data from, gets rebuilt?

I have not registered this controller as controller rendering because apparently we don't need to do that and it just works out-of-box. I just read the JSON output by an ajax call through jQuery and the javascript code and HTML markup is inside a MVC view rendering. I guess it doesn't make sense to setup cache on the view rendering. Isn't it?

What should i do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best option would be to use the HtmlCache and store the data there. This cache gets completed cleared on a publish, so it would make sense to use it.

You can add an entry into the cache by using the `SetHtml` method:

```
var cache = Sitecore.Caching.CacheManager.GetHtmlCache(Sitecore.Context.Site);
var json = cache.GetHtml("mycachekey");
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(json))
{
    var json = // build your json output here
    cache.SetHtml("mycachekey", jsonValue);
}
return json;
```

Comment: Thanks Richard. I though there is some sort of facility, ready to use on ServiceApiController level. So, we can just use a custom cache, right? BTW, what if I just rebuild the index on backend instead of publishing?

Comment: If you use a Custom Cache you will need to hook into the `publish:end` and `publish:end:remote` events and clear that cache in custom code. If you use the `HtmlCache` that will be cleared by Sitecore.

Comment: If you manually rebuild the indexes, you will have to clear the cache yourself, either by running a publish after rebuilding or using the `/admin/cache.aspx` admin page.